# Access to aliased functions in a Python module

Tags: python

I am consolidating many shell-like operations into a single module.  I would then like to be able to do:

```
pyscript.py:
from shell import *
basename("/path/to/file.ext")
```

and the shell.py module contains:

```
shell.py:
from os.path import basename
```

The problem is that functions imported to the shell module are not available, since the import statement only includes functions, classes, and globals *defined* in the "shell" module, not ones that are imported.

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Does import `package.module.object` even work? (Edit: Tried it out, doesn't work in 3.1) Anyway, you certainly want `from os.path import basename`.

Comment: @delnan: Please post this as an answer.

Comment: self-comment: This is a bogus question.  I have a scenario where something similar to this occurs but I have not yet isolated it.  The scenario I describe above (now corrected) does, in fact, work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you're not just using the wrong syntax? This works for me in 2.6.

```
from shell import * 
basename("/path/to/file.ext")
```

shell.py:

```
from os.path import basename
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug, it's a feature :-)

If you import m1 in a module m2 and then import m2 into another module, it will only import things from m2, not from m1. This is to prevent namespace pollution.

You could do this:

shell.py:

```
import os.path
basename = os.path.basename
```

Then, in pyscript.py, you can do this:

```
from shell import * # warning: bad style!
basename(...)
```